# change the font color based on value angular js

Tags: angularjs, css

I am using AngularJS and I use `ng-repeat` to loop and show the details in the page.

Is there a possibility to change the font color based on the value?

```
<li ng-repeat="s in vm.States" >                        
  <span>{{s.Name}}</span>
  <span>{{s.state}}</span>
 </li>

Test1 -Error(Red)
Test2 - Warning(blue)
Test3 - Ignored(green)
```

Here `s.state` value can be Error, Warning or Ignored
Can I show different font colors for these states via angular or css?

Comment: check `ng-class` or `ng-style`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can achieve this with following code:

```
<li ng-repeat="s in vm.States" >                        
  <span>{{s.Name}}</span>
  <span ng-class="{'color-red': s.state === 'Error', 'color-blue': s.state === 'Warning', 'color-green': s.state === 'Ignored'}">{{s.state}}</span>
</li>
```

Where `'color-red', 'color-blue', 'color-green'` are your css classes.

See it in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DXSzxz?p=preview).

[Check documentation about ng-class.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Answer (score 8):

It might be worth also taking a look over [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) which is the same as [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) but provides conditional inline syling such as

```
<li ng-repeat="s in vm.States" >                        
  <span>{{s.Name}}</span>
  <span ng-style="{'color: red': s.state === 'Error', 'color: blue': s.state === 'Warning', 'color: green': s.state === 'Ignored'}">{{s.state}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it very easily by `ng-class` and css.

CSS code

```
.Error{color: red;}
.Warning{color: blue;}
.Ignored{color: green;}
```

Html code

```
<li ng-repeat="s in vm.States" >                        
  <span>{{s.Name}}</span>
  <span ng-class="s.state">{{s.state}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this example

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);

myApp
    .controller('MyCtrl1', function ($scope) {
        $scope.vm = {
            States: [
                {
                    Name: 'Error',
                    state: 'error',
                    color: 'red'
                },
                {
                    Name: 'Warning',
                    state: 'warning',
                    color: 'blue'
                },
                {
                    Name: 'Ignored',
                    state: 'ignored',
                    color: 'green'
                }
            ]
        };
    })
```

```css
.red{
    color: red;
}

.blue{
    color: blue;   
}

.green{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
        <li ng-repeat="s in vm.States" >                        
          <span ng-class="s.color">{{s.Name}}</span> - 
          <span ng-class="s.color">{{s.state}}</span>
         </li>
    </div>
 </div>
```