# change the font color based on value that is being filtered angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Though the question similar to [change the font color based on value angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243965/change-the-font-color-based-on-value-angular-js) But what if we are using a filter in the expression like:

HTML:

```
<span ng-class="{'time-elapsed': timestamp | timeElapsed != 'LIVE','time-elapsed-live': timestamp | timeElapsed == 'LIVE'}">{{timestamp | timeElapsed}}</span>
```

CSS:

```
.time-elapsed {
    color: black;
}
.time-elapsed-live {
    color: red;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
angular.module('appName', [])
.filter('timeElapsed', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
      if(!input) {
        return "";
      }
      var currDate = new Date(Date.now());
      var inputDate = new Date(input);
      var diffDate = Math.abs(currDate.getTime()-inputDate.getTime());
      var diffHrs = Math.floor(diffDate/(1000 * 60 * 60));

      if(diffHrs < 1) {
        return "LIVE";
      }

      if(diffHrs < 24) {
        return diffHrs.toString() + "h";
      }

      var diffDays = Math.floor(diffHrs/24);

      if(diffDays<31)
        return diffDays.toString() + "d";

      var diffMonths=Math.floor(diffDays/31);

      if(diffMonths<12)
        return diffMonths.toString()+"mo";

      return Math.floor(diffMonths/12).toString()+"y";
    }
  }])
```

This code is giving me errors because apparently we can't put an expression like "timestamp | timeElapsed != 'LIVE'" inside ng-class. What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try calling a function instead of calling filter directly.

Change like this

```
<span ng-class="getTimeElapsedClass(timestamp)">{{timestamp | timeElapsed}}</span>
```

inject your filter in the controller just appending the "Filter" after your filters name

Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302267/how-to-use-a-filter-in-a-controller) for more info on this.

in your controller define this function like this

```
$scope.getTimeElapsedClass = function(timestamp ){
  var filterResult = timeElapsedFilter(timestamp)
  if(filterResult !== 'Live'){
     return 'time-elapsed'
  } else{
      return 'time-elapsed-live'
   }
}
```