# Angular 7 change color of text based on value from JSON list

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to change the color of some text if the value from a list.  If the value is less than or equal to 4 then red, if greater than 4 green.

Based on this question and answer - [change the font color based on value angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30243965/change-the-font-color-based-on-value-angular-js)

I have written the following:

```
   <mat-card-header ng-repeat="let item of lstonofflinegt1">
            <mat-card-title>My Title</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle ng-class="{'color:#2ecc71': item.value > 4, 'color:#e74c3c': item.value < 4}">ONLINE</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
```

Nothing happens to the text.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are adding style property insted of class

Comment: Instead of ng-class try ngStyle

Comment: If this is Angular 7, why are you using `ng-repeat` and `ng-class`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`<mat-card-subtitle [ngStyle]="{'color': item.value > 4 ? '#2ecc71': '#e74c3c'}">ONLINE</mat-card-subtitle>`